# Bootstrap help-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use the help-block for showing a message on invalid input, however I do not like how it seems that it 'pushes' the rest of the input elements further down.

There is sufficient space between the two form inputs, and I'd like the message to be 'absolute'

To demonstrate what I mean:

Here is how the form looks like: http://prntscr.com/65dojx
And here is how it looks like with invalid input: http://prntscr.com/65dp0o

The error message for invalid email 'pushes' down the password form input and does not look smooth at all.

Alternatively, if there is a way to make this appear more smooth, that might work.

Comment: Forgot to ask, is this the normal behavior of help-block?

Comment: just give it `position: absolute` and play around with it until you have what you need..

Comment: Yes, this is how `display: block` works. And `.help-block` uses that (hence its name)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a normal behavior unless you position it absolutely. If you are looking for a way for it to appear smoothly. Try adding some transitions to the help-blocks. You may also have to add it to the form container as well.

```
#help-block{

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
```